# How can I compare Pearson's Correlations from a "Mini Meta"?

Tags: meta-analysis, pearson-r

I'm trying to conduct a "mini" meta-analysis on a series of 6 studies I've conducted. With regards to the mini meta itself, I've used the steps outlined in this article (and the associated excel spreadsheet for calculations): https://www.researchgate.net/publication/309411119_Mini_Meta-Analysis_of_Your_Own_Studies_Some_Arguments_on_Why_and_a_Primer_on_How

For the "mini-meta" calculations, I've used the "3.Meta-analysis r" tab of the Excel template available here: https://osf.io/6tfh5/

The focus of my article is to see which of two variables (X & Y) have the strongest association with a dependent variable (Z) across the studies. I have calculated the Mean r for all relevant relationships (X-Z; Y-Z; X-Y) across all studies using the mini meta spreadsheet, and was intending to use a test of the difference between two dependent correlations with one variable in common to see whether there is a significant difference between X-Z and Y-Z.

To do this, I was intending to use the calculator at the following link: http://quantpsy.org/corrtest/corrtest2.htm

I am wondering if it would be legitimate for me to enter the Mean r for each relationship and the pooled total sample size across the 6 studies into the above calculator to answer my research question, or if this would not be adequately taking into account the fact the correlations do not come from a single sample? I can see that the Mean R calculated in the spreadsheet takes into account each study's weight, so perhaps it is appropriate. If it's not inappropriate, then I would definitely appreciate any guidance anyone could provide.

Thanks to anyone who can assist!